# MalformedParameterizedTypeException when running Mybatis App

Tags: spring, mybatis

here's the stacktrace:

Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

I used the libraries that came w/ the mybatis-spring 1.1.1 and I added the spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar. My IDE is JDeveloper 11.1.2.1.0. here's the contents of WEB-INF/lib

aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
jettison-1.1.jar 
mybatis-3.1.1.jar 
mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar 
mybatis-spring-1.1.1-javadoc.jar 
mybatis-spring-1.1.1-sources.jar 
spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar 
spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar 
spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar 
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar 
xstream-1.3.jar

here's the contents of applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="ph.com.aub.util"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="ph.com.aub.mappers" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
<value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you post your xml applicationContext.xml?

Comment: What about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using wrong libs: you should use mybatis-3.1.0

[spring-mybatis-integration](http://anirbanchowdhury.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/spring-mybatis-integration-part-1/)

Comment: still cant get it to work. i tried downloading the JPetstore app from the mybatis web site. I added the libraries from the JPetstore app to my proj. and now I get the ff: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;                                            I dont have any spring 2 jars on my classpath. Is there an issue w/ Jdeveloper and mybatis?

Comment: got it working finally. i added a weblogic.xml file w/ the ff contents: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
<container-descriptor>
   <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>